# Increasing AC frequency vs increasing number of phases

Tags: ac, frequency

An AC signal has a certain frequency which according to my understanding is the switches between the two extremes of the voltage per second. While my outlets around here typically seem to have a single signal of that form (1 live, 1 neutral, maybe 1 ground) I have read about systems that overlay multiple signals with a phase offset (i.e 3 phase AC output).

Picturing two phases it seems that you will no longer have a alternating voltage between -xV and +xV but by switching between phases you can get a voltage alternating between +xV and 0V at twice the frequency.

Consider the following image:
[image]

If you switch between red and blue vs neutral at the right interval you will alternate between +xV and 0V (at twice the frequency of each of the phases).

I was wondering, can you theoretically achieve a similar result by increasing the frequency of a single phase?

Comment: AC \$\ne\$ DC...  3 phase ac means three sinewaves phase shifted by 120 degrees.

Comment: Yes, obviously?

Comment: As in you get 3 220V sinewaves alternating between +220V to -220V.

Comment: Three phase power uses three wires, one for each phase, and possibly a fourth wire for neutral.  Many three phase loads, like large motors, don't use a neutral connection. In North America, normal outlet voltage is 120 V.  If three phase power is available (as in many commercial/industrial settings), you would have 208 volts between phases, but 120 V phase to neutral.

Comment: Yes, and if you compare voltage to netural with each of them in the right interval you should at most alternate between 220V and 0V for two phases or 220V and whatever sin/cos for 3 phases where the voltage of the previous phase exceeds the one of the next phase, right? So in theory with an infinite amount of phases or an infinitely high frequency you should get 220V in theory?

Comment: You're mixing up a bunch of different things, including the fact that the RMS voltage (eg, your 220) is not the peak excursion in either direction, but rather the equivalent DC voltage which would deliver the same power to a purely restive load.  It *is* true that multi-phase AC provides smoother power delivery; eg, if you have a rectifier and capacitor bank feeding a DC load (such as a programmable frequency inverter in a modern motor drive), you need smaller capacitors if you feed it with 3-phase input rather than single phase.

Comment: I think you need to brush up on some of the math involved.  You can't create a new frequency by adding signals of the same frequency.  Here is an interesting tool to help experiment with the ideas: https://www.geogebra.org/m/DNbv8gtu

Comment: If you feel like your comment is not intended to make me change my question, please feel free to post it as an answer :)

Comment: In terms of the size of the capacitors you would need to convert to DC, multi-phase AC feed to your rectifiers actually is somewhat similar in effect to having a higher line frequency.  But you don't typically get the opportunity of a higher frequency on a distribution grid, it exists locally in things like aircraft but would cause problems over large areas (actually, some modern long-haul distribution feed is high voltage DC with solid state conversion!).   You do get 3-phase grids because it's by far the best *simple* way to make an industrial-sized induction motor spin.

Comment: Since this seems to have caused some confusion I have removed the DC part altogether, since this was not really what I was interested in anyway.

Comment: The two phase case is equivalent to 1 phase at double the voltage, so it's not helpful. You need to consider the three phase case instead.

Comment: "*An AC signal has a certain frequency which according to my understanding is the switches between the two extremes of the voltage per second.*" No, it is the inverse of the time period between **the same** points of the waveform on consecutive cycles of the waveform - the positive peaks, for example, not the time between the positive and negative peaks.

Answer (score 2):

> it seems that you will no longer have a alternating voltage between -xV and +xV but by switching between phases you can get a voltage alternating between +xV and 0V at twice the frequency.

That is incorrect, but it's an understandable error.  It would appear you're perhaps being confused by the "goofy" situation of US domestic power to electric cookers, water heaters, laundry dryers, etc.

First, let's consider the fundamental facts of AC power: the AC component of a signal necessarily *alternates* around its ground, and such alternation is *inherently symmetric* as a matter of *definition*.  Any offset or asymmetry from ground is a DC component, and while that might *locally* exist, it cannot pass through transformers widely present in a grid, so in a conceptual analysis it can be ignored.

So what is present on that clothes dryer outlet?

In a typical US residence, two *opposite* AC waveforms.  When one is high, the other is low, and so on.  The voltage between them is 240 volts RMS; the voltage between either and neutral is 120 volts and used for simpler loads.

But many industrial/commercial buildings are actually fed with 3 phase power, as that is more suitable for industrial loads like large induction motors.  Instead of the 180 degree phasing of domestic power, industrial/commerical power is distributed at three equal points stepped 120 degrees around the phase circle.  Typically in such a setup, each phase to neutral measures 120 volts RMS, so simple single-phase outlets can be provided.  But since the phases only differ by 120 degrees instead of 180, if you measure the RMS voltage across any two (which is to say, measure the degree to which they are opposite) you'll only get a trigonometrically reduced 208 volts.  Install a domestic model electric cooker or clothes dryer at work, and it may be under-powered, though such simple resistive loads may not particularly care.

(There are also other 3-phase distributions schemes at higher voltage, "wild leg" etc - trying to keep this simple)

Comment: Wait! A center-tapped transformer secondary is "goofy?"

Comment: @Solomon, it's goofy when it's a centre-tap of a delta-wired three-phase transformer system as it gives a "high leg" and destroys the elegant symmetry of a three-phase system.with star-connected neutral. To European eyes it always looks like a hack.

Comment: OK, Yeah. There's just one phase of high-voltage feeding my street, so sometimes I forget about that stuff. I know a guy who wanted some extra light over a workbench in a lab in a commercial building where we worked, So he ran out to the DIY store, bought light fixtures, and wired them up himself after the cleaners had gone home. He didn't realize that the overhead lighting in the building was 277 Volts (phase-to-neutral voltage of a 480V, 3-phase, star-wired circuit.) Oops! That was bit much for the 120V fixtures that he bought. You're right. We do have some goofy **** here.